# Title: Issue with Python Requests Module: SSL Certificate Verification Error

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, discord.py, setup.py

I'm encountering an SSL certificate verification error while using the Python Requests module to make API requests. The error message I'm getting is:

requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:XXX)

I have already tried this things

1. Updating the Requests module to the latest version.
2. Disabling SSL verification using the **`verify`** parameter in the **`requests.get`** function (not recommended for production).